# Cordova How to check if my iOS app was purchased in Apple Store

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have my paid iOS app in appstore, for now users must buy an app using Apple services in order to use it. 
I want to move my app to free model.
I want to give some exclusive features for legacy users who brought old version of the app.

How can i check if user purchased an old version of the app?

I tried different cordova plugins including AlexDislers and others but none of them seem to work for me
Any Suggestions?

Comment: Does your APP rely on an database? If so, all users that were created before the switch to the free model are automatically legacy users, aren't they? :-)

Comment: Just check the version and build in your app.

Comment: @Joerg when i test it using account without purchase i still get valid receipt with valid original_purchase_date and build version always the last

Comment: @PhilippMaurer no my app don't rely on the database

Comment: Since you do not have a database the solution of @Joerg would not work either, because if a user buys a new phone, he would need to reinstall the app and therefore be flagged as non legacy, eventhough he is a legacy user. I do not know how to achieve this behavior without a database, but maybe you can find out when a user got your app for the first time from the app store. Anyway you will need to rely on information given by the store, if any.